# How to insert nested json data in mysql table?

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I am trying to update my mysql table and insert `json` data to my `mysql` table's `json-datatype` column using `JSON_INSERT`. Here is the structure of my column.

```
{
"Data": 
     [{
      "Devce": "ios", 
      "Status": 1
      }]
}
```

This is the query I am using to `insert` more data to this field.

```
UPDATE table SET `Value` = JSON_INSERT
(`Value`,'$.Data','{\"Device\":\"ios\",\"Status\":1}') WHERE Meta = 'REQUEST_APP'
```

This is supposed to update the field to this:

```
{
    "Data": 
         [{
          "Devce": "ios", 
          "Status": 1
          },
    {
          "Devce": "ios", 
          "Status": 1
          }
]
    }
```

But instead it the result is:

> 0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0241 seconds.)

Any help regarding this would be appreciated.

Comment: I am using PHP, so for me Yes :)

Comment: `JSON_APPEND` may serve your purpose better [JSON_APPEND doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-append)

Comment: If you help me make it work on phpmyadmin I will make it work myself. The php code may make the question unclear.

Comment: @Carlos it worked for me. Please answer it so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JSON_APPEND` serves your purpose better [JSON_APPEND docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-append)